# ASP.Net: How to log login-trys correctly?

Tags: asp.net

I have a login in my admin page.

Now I want to log every login-try in my database.
Normaly I have a Log-table with the adminID in a foreign key of the adminuser-table.

Now, of course, when someone try to login with a username that doesn't exist, I haven't a ID and the foraign-key uses a crash in the write-attamp.

Now whats the correct way to log a login-try when the username isn't correct and you haven't the correct id?

1) Add a second log-table for such things
or 2) Remove the foraign Key in the first log-table

Comment: You do realize that your table is a vector for an DOS attack? All I have to do is setup a bot to attempt bad logins, will fill up table, disk, bring the site down...

Comment: So whats the solution? Do no login-try log?

Comment: Limit the size of the table is one solution (delete old entries as you add new ones) or don't log failed attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have the adminID field as a nullable field? That way, you could distinguish between successful and unsuccessful login attempts.

Comment: Is an idea, okay, but will the Foraign-key not crash too?

Comment: Not sure what database you are using, but in MS SQL, if you've a FK field, set to nullable, it's not going to cause problems, if you insert a null value into it.